# Statically allocated buffer using templates

Tags: c++, inheritance

I want to have some classes that would contain arrays of different sizes. I want this to be statically allocated because it is intended for an embedded system. The only good solution I can think of is using templates.

However, I want to use the same class type to access those objects.

This is my solution so far.

```
class Base
{
public:
    Base(char* _data, int _size) :
        data(_data), size(_size) {}

    char* getData(void)
    {
        return data;
    }

    int getSize(void)
    {
        return size;
    }

protected:
    char* const data;
    const int size;
};

template <int sz>
class Foo : public Base
{
public:
    Foo() : Base(dataBuff, sizeof(dataBuff)) {}
private:
    char dataBuff[sz];
};

// Here I can access every template that inherits Base class
void printFoo(Base* base)
{
    std::cout << base->getData() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "size is " << base->getSize() << std::endl;
}

int main(void)
{
    Foo<20> foo;

    char* data = foo.getData();
    strcpy(data, "Hello world");
    printFoo(&foo);
    return 0;
}
```

Of course the reason for this is to have more methods in the base class for appending deleting and searching for data.

Is this something valid? This is something very basic.
Can I have a better solution?

EDIT: Fixed bug (typo).

Comment: Why not use [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)? If that's not available in your embedded environment, then perhaps it is better to reimpkement it, so you can write `array<char, 20> foo;`

Comment: @G.Sliepen I have to check if `std::array` is suitable without adding too much overhead (program memory, RAM etc..). I'll look at it for sure! Thank you for your comment!

Comment: std::array will add space to the current scope (so no dynamic memory allocation). While std::vector gives you dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: PS. This is broken. The compiler told you it was broken and you cast away the error. `(char*)& dataBuff`: Don't use C cast it says I know better than the compiler (which is usually not the case). It gets rid of your error message but the problem is still there.

Comment: @MartinYork That was a mistake! Thank you for pointing out! Fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Use `std::array` if possible

You can get a statically allocated buffer using [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array). Its implementation is very similar to your `Foo`, with the added benefit that it works like any other STL container. Here is how you would use it:

```
#include <array>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::array<char, 20> foo;
    strcpy(foo.data(), "Hello world");
    std::cout << foo.data() << "\nSize is " << foo.size() << '\n';
}
```

## About static allocation

In your example, `foo` is not allocated statically, rather it is allocated on the stack. You could prepend `static` in front of it and/or declare that variable outside a function to ensure it is really allocated statically.

Then the question is whether this will save you any memory. Many embedded systems do allow dynamic allocation of heap memory. Sure, there is some overhead associated with it, but an advantage is that you only allocate as much as you need, whereas with an array of a static size, you might have to reserve more memory than you are going to need. What is best depends on the situation.

## About type erasure

> However, I want to use the same class type to access those objects.

I don't see a reason for that in your example usage. But if you do need to pass something like a pointer to `Base` along, consider that you don't need inheritance; you can have a separate class that stores a pointer to the array and a size, like [`std::span`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span) for arrays, or [`std::string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) for strings in particular. Here is an example using `std::span` that matches your example:

```
#include <array>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <span>

void printFoo(std::span<char> base)
{
    std::cout << base.data() << "\nSize is " << base.size() << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    std::array<char, 20> foo;
    strcpy(foo.data(), "Hello world");
    printFoo(foo);
}
```

If you cannot use `std::array` and/or `std::span` on your embedded system, I recommend you try to implement them yourself. Your code already has parts of it, you just need some name changes and to not use the span as a base class for the array anymore.